# Summing a non arithmetic and non geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I am looking to dollar cost average into a stock and got curious on how many shares i would actually get if i invested a constant amount of money into a continuously increasing share price. this got me thinking of a formula to use to quickly do this and I came to this series. I want to find the sum of a finite series starting  $$\dfrac{1}{200} + \dfrac{1}{199} + \dfrac{1}{198}+\ldots \dfrac{1}{180}.$$
Also expressed as [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtuVZ.png), or [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxJoh.png). I cannot figure out a faster way to find the solution aside from manually summing all 20 terms. Should I write my expressions in a different way or is there another formula to use?

Comment: Harmonic Sums are given by Abels Partial summation formula a very Well defined work in T. Apostol Analytic N.T

Comment: In fact see Wiki Writing in Google Harmonic Siries

Comment: In Wiki it was not well derived but In apostol it was well derived.

Comment: There are more than $20$ terms.

Comment: Thank you Happie, is that the only way to solve this problem, the formula seems ideal for series with many more terms, but it still seems like the most efficient method for a problem this small is just to manually sum it.

Comment: Actually,  I no logerbpost solutions on MSE but I believe there might be other ways of doing it, totally not sure but If I found One I will post. $\int_{180}^{201} \frac{1}{[x]} dx$ and some approximation and calculating the error term helps May be.

Comment: logerbpost=longer be posting

Comment: Mathematica gives `Total[1/Range[180,200]]=20758932081518884288258012789771/187627987984843466533341247579200` if that's useful. I don't think there is another simpler approach than just summing, for an exact solution.

Comment: A faster Mathematica statement is `HarmonicNumber[200] - HarmonicNumber[179]`. This also is the same type of statement that could be used in Sagemath, Maple, or defined in Magma Computational.

Comment: If this question does not meet Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines then how has it received a score of 4?

Answer (score 8):

If you are optimistic, since you sum is

`HarmonicNumber[200] - HarmonicNumber[179]`

use the asymptotics
$$H_p=(\log (p)+\gamma )+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ to make
$$H_a-H_b\sim\log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)-\frac{1}{12} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)$$For your numbers, it would give
$$\log \left(\frac{200}{179}\right)-\frac{1500947}{5126560000}=\color{red}{0.11063878211}89$$ instead of the exact   $0.1106387821160$

**Edit**

If the number of terms is limited (as in your case), you can also get rid of the logarithm and write

$$H_a-H_b\sim 2\frac{a-b}{a+b}+\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}\right)-\frac{1}{12} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)$$

Comment: I tried to use your formula to answer this: $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{10}$. When I plugged $a=9$ and $b=1$, the result was $~0.5921$. But when I plugged $a=1$ and $b=9$, the result was $~-0.5921$. But the real answer when I just summed the fractions was $\frac{7381}{2520}$ or $~2.928968254$. What's the problem here?!

Comment: @SnackExchange. I started writing *"if you are optimistic"*. Using the asymptotics of $H_p$ means that $p$ is "sufficiently" large.

Comment: @SnackExchange. Take $a=20$ and $b=9$ to get $0.76877261$ instead of $0.76877140$

Comment: Why 20 and 9? Also, I didn't reach $0.76877140$ as the answer.

Comment: With the logarithm-free formula, my answer even differed from the one I obtained using the logarithmic formula!